# Vailidity of Digital signatures on self-prepared 1040 tax form

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

Me and my wife are stuck in INDIA due to lock-down, courier services, flights etc are suspended till 4/14. I want to file my past due return (2016), IRS accepts it only by mail.

I'm considering following two options, could anyone confirm if they are acceptable by IRS ?

**1) SCAN, EMAIL, PRINT and MAIL**

- Ink sign (me & wife) the signature page of 1040 form
- Email high resolution scanned image of signature page + remaining PDF to family in USA
- Color Print all pages in USA and
- MAIL to IRS from USA.

I went through [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83086/is-it-acceptable-to-sign-form-1040-on-the-computer-and-print-it-with-the-signatu) thread and know that SCAN is not an option, I am still asking to see if anything changed between then and now.

**2) DocuSign, EMAIL, PRINT and MAIL**

- Use DocuSign service to capture digital signature (me & wife) with datetime stamp
- Email DocuSigned signature page + remaining PDF to family in USA
- Color Print all pages in USA and
- MAIL to IRS from USA.

**Could anyone help to confirm acceptability of above options please ?**